# Multiple Authors with common affiliations in IEEEtran conference template

Tags: titles, ieeetran, affiliation

I have a paper where I have 4 different authors with a common affiliation. I would like to mention there names and then a single affiliation followed by individual mail addresses. I have included the code I have and the format snapshot I would like to have. I am using TexStudio and am new to LaTeX. Please help me and tell me the correct use of \author for this.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\title{CNFET-Based 0.1 V to 0.6 V DC/DC Converter}


% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Aditya Tyagi}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\ and Montgomery Scott}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is how I would like to have it.]

Answer (score 69):

I suggest you use the "long form" suggestion in the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran), combing this with `\IEEEauthorrefmark` to attach footnote symbols to tie the pieces of information together:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Whatever,
Whichever University\\
Wherever\\
Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, this is very great solution. How can I indicate the last author mask is the corresponding author? The mask often appears as start

Comment: @Jame You can just write `\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Corresponding author` at whatever position you want this to appear in the block, add `\\` before or after for a linebreak.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you have multiple authors with one or more people having multiple affiliations:

Use package

```
\usepackage{authblk}
```

Then, at the place of authors:

```
\author[1]{FN1 LN1}
\author[1,2]{FN2 LN2}
\affil[1]{University of Southern California, Los Angeles, CA \authorcr Email: {\tt \{uid1, uid2\}@usc.edu}\vspace{1.5ex}}
\affil[2]{NASA Jet Propulsion Laboratory, Pasadena, CA \authorcr Email: {\tt uid3@jpl.nasa.gov} \vspace{-2ex}}
```

Note that `\vspace{1.5ex}` and `\vspace{-2ex}` to adjust vertical space padding.

Comment: authrblk gives `FN1 LN1, and FN2 LN2`. The `AND` is really strange in a research paper