# No Line Break in Author Command? It goes off the page!

Tags: titles, ieeetran

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160052/67392) by @AndrewSwann demonstrates use of the `\author{}` command. I am writing an article with a bunch of authors, and when I use this command, it goes off the page:

[image]

How can I fix this? Using the same code with more authors:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Five\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Six\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Seven\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Eight\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Nine\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Author Ten\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Whatever,
Whichever University\\
Wherever\\
Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `\\` at suitable spots: here one suffices after the fifth author.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Five\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},\\
Author Six\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Seven\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Eight\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Nine\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Author Ten\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Whatever,
Whichever University\\
Wherever\\
Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use a `\parbox` of `\linewidth` and use `%` to hide spurious spaces.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{%
  \IEEEauthorblockN{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
      Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
      Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
      Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
      Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
      Author Five\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
      Author Six\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
      Author Seven\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
      Author Eight\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
      Author Nine\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
      Author Ten\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}%
    }%
  }%
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    Department of Whatever, Whichever University\\
    Wherever\\
    Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net%
  }%
}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]